# image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and this is the basic image displaying code that I found on the internet.

```
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = r'.\0030001621.jpg'

root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

This is giving this error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-ed688d6a5ab6> in <module>
          7 root = tk.Tk()
          8 img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    ----> 9 panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
         10 panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
         11 root.mainloop()

    c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
       2764 
       2765         """
    -> 2766         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
       2767 
       2768 class Listbox(Widget, XView, YView):

    c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
       2297             del cnf[k]
       2298         self.tk.call(
    -> 2299             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
       2300         for k, v in classes:
       2301             k.configure(self, v)

    TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you import the posted code from another python script with another `tkinter` instance?

Comment: Your code is 100% correct.

Comment: Try using the command: ```pip install pyimage```

Comment: If that doesn't work. I think you haven't checked the "Add python to path" checkbox. while installing python. If that is the case try uninstalling python and then reinstall python and don't forget to check the "Add python to path" checkbox this time

Comment: It seems like that there is already an instance of `tkinter` running when you execute the code in `ipython`.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly make sure you have given the correct path for the image.*

And then try the following method,

Try keeping a reference of the image to the Tkinter object.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = r'mposter.jpg'

root = tk.Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)

# keep a reference
panel.image = img

panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

You can read about this in much more detail

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Answer (score -1):

Your code is 100% correct.

I think you haven't checked the "Add python to path" checkbox. while installing python. If that is the case try uninstalling Python and then reinstall python and don't forget to check the "Add python to path" checkbox this time.

Comment: The question is asking about an _object_ named `pyimage4`, not a module named `pyimage`.